# Cant open vector asset panel android studio 4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

I create a drawable vector like usual, right-click at the res/drawable file, then click create vector asset to open asset studio.
but when I want to search vector by clicking square box next to clip art, it won't open next popup. Note, I can still able to create vector manually or using current "ic_android_black24dp" vector

The problem occurs after my pc force shutdown.

[image: vector asset panel wont show]

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem after my Dell was forced to shutdown.
i tried: invalidate cache and restart, then: restore default settings.

it didn't work, but maybe it will for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from similar symptoms.

setting -> Appearance&Behavior -> MemorySettings

Changing the heap size may work

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#adjusting_heap_size